# Redux-Saga App SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. The above error occurred in task created by sagaWatcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

My code at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-cache-9b694?file=/src/actions.js

I'm new in Redux-saga. When component is mounted, fetching data and rendering to component. The data is **successfully fetching from server and setting it to state**. But at the end in console I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
The above error occurred in task fetchData created by takeEvery(FETCH_DATA, fetchData)created by sagaWatcher
Tasks cancelled due to error: takeEvery(FETCH_DATA, fetchData)
```

Here's my code:

**component.js**

```js
const Lists = () => {
  const data = useSelector(state => state.results, shallowEqual);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(FETCH_DATA('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'))
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    data.map(item => <List val={item.name} key={item.id} />)
  )
};
```

**actions.js**

```js
export const SET_CHARACTERS = (data) => ({
  type: 'SET_CHARACTERS',
  payload: data,
});

export const FETCH_FAILED = (payload) => ({
  type: 'FETCH_FAILED',
  payload,
});

export const FETCH_DATA = (url) => ({type: 'FETCH_DATA', payload: url});
```

**reducer.js**

```js
export const charactersReducer = (state = {results: []}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_CHARACTERS':
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    case 'FETCH_FAILED':
      return console.log('%cUSER FETCH FAILED: %s', 'color: red', action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**getData.js**

```js
const fetchList = async (url) => {
  const rawData = await fetch(url);
  return await rawData.json();
};
```

**saga.js**

```js
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(charactersReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(logger, sagaMiddleware), ReduxDevTools.instrument()));

function* fetchData(action) {
  const data = yield call(fetchList, action.payload);
  yield put(SET_CHARACTERS(data));
}

function* sagaWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(FETCH_DATA, fetchData);
}

sagaMiddleware.run(sagaWatcher);
```

What's wrong with my code?

As seen in screenshot below, when component is mounted I'm **getting fetched data and set it to state**, and rendering it into the DOM.
[image]

Sorry if it's duplicate question, I didn't find answer.

Comment: Look at your Network tab to see what data the JSON request actually returned!

Comment: It sounds like error coming from loading remote data. Try to try/catch in your `fetchData` then log the error to see what's going on

Comment: @tmhao2005 , when wrapping with try/catch, logs the same error, but recursively

Comment: @deceze , returned data is empty HTML, I know that, but why I get that HTML...that HTML seems like my empty HTML file from public folder

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found solution here.
[Infinite loop with redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993560/infinite-loop-with-redux-saga)
The problem was that in `saga.js` I'm putting action creator to `takeEvery` and `call` tasks. In fact I needed to put string.
Now it works.
Maybe this question will be helpful to others in future.

Thank you guys.