# Infinite loop in redux-saga effect

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I've been able to create an infinite loop that keeps getting data from the API.

I use useEffect conditional dispatch to run, which should only run once.

But when I look into Redux DevTools, the data retrieval from the api is in an endless loop.

**Slice:**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = { cats: [] };

const catSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cat",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCat: (state, action) => {
      state.cats = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setCat } = catSlice.actions;

export default catSlice.reducer;
```

**Saga:**

```js
import { call, put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setCat } from "./catSlice";

function* getCatsFetch() {
  const cats = yield call(() => fetch(`https://xxxapi.com`));
  const formatedCats = yield cats.json();
  yield put(setCat(formatedCats));
}

function* catSaga() {
  yield takeLatest("cat/setCats", getCatsFetch);
}

export default catSaga;
```

**Command in App.js**

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setCats());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Can you please help me stop endless requests on the api? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite loop with redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993560/infinite-loop-with-redux-saga)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `getCatsFetch` saga emits a `setCat` action. And your `catSaga` is waiting for any `setCat` to trigger another `getCatsFetch` saga. So even though you're only dispatching one `setCat` action from your component, the saga is also emitting a `setCat` after it successfully runs. You're looping through the middleware.

To correct the issue, you should probably change the `takeLatest` to be looking for some kind of `getCats` action instead, then emit that action in your component. (not your saga).